# Format Unix Timestamp with Timezone?

Tags: php

Lets say I've got my Unix Timestamp of 1373623247.  Now I understand that the timestamps are just seconds since X.  The issue I have is the formatting of it.

The server I use is hosted in  Germany, however I am in the UK so the output is 12-07-13 12:01:01, when actually its only 11:01:01 here.

The code I am using is as below:

```
$date = 1373623247;
echo date("j-m-y h:i:s",$date);
```

What I did was use date_create and timezone as follows:

```
$date1 = date("j-m-y h:i:s",$date);
$dateobj = date_create("$date1", timezone_open('Europe/London'));
echo date_format($dateobj,"j-m-y h:i:s") . "\n";
```

The issue I now have is that it's actually adjusted the date to tomorrow, and hasn't altered the time!

Comment: Use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set your timezone.

Comment: You are not getting tomorrow. `12-07-13` is parsed as `2012-07-13`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to involve `date` at all:

```
$date = 1373623247;
$dateobj = date_create_from_format("U", $date);
date_timezone_set($dateobj, timezone_open('Europe/London'));
echo date_format($dateobj,"j-m-y h:i:s") . "\n";
```

This code converts the timestamp directly to a `DateTime` instance using the `U` [format specifier](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). It's both shorter and cleaner to not work with `date`, as you don't need to worry about the server's default timezone at all.

Pro tip: `date` and `strtotime` get much coverage, and in certain cases are very convenient, but `DateTime` can do everything on its own and IMHO results in code that is much more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.  Now just the issue around Greenwich Mean Time and British Summer Time...

Comment: @K20GH: I just realized that and edited to reflect. The correct thing to do is parse the timestamp and *then* assert that you want it to be considered as London local time.